# Get status of an upload to Drive REST API

Tags: file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api, resume-upload

I am creating a form in HTML5 and using Drive API rest to upload files, but the files are large, so I need to consult the current status of the upload. I'm using `uploadType = resumable`, but to make the status request as documentation:

```
[Google documentation][1]
PUT} {session_uri HTTP / 1.1
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes * / *
```

The response from the server does not return the Range received.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I do not know if understood the question. What I need is to show a progress bar when uploading files to Google Drive via Drive Rest Api.

Comment: I believe in order to check for progress, you need to use [multipart upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart). When using multipart, you can check for the status of the upload between parts.

Comment: But in the google documentation says I should use `uploadType = resumable`, so the api returns a URL that can be used to check the status of the upload. Until there all right, but when I use the URL returned to checkar status does not.